# What is the Easiest way to fix the Ajax conflict error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my website (http://urlsaf.com/m8) I already added one Ajax based rating system but this system is not working properly. When ever I rate it, It's reloaded the page. In my past this Ajax based rating system was rated successfully without reload the page using XMLHttpRequest. Below I will give my rating.js and behavior.js for your reference. Anyone please give the solution for my Ajax conflict error. *Thanks in advance.*

**1.rating.js**

```
var xmlhttp if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
     try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp=false
     }
    }
    function myXMLHttpRequest() {
      var xmlhttplocal;
      try {
        xmlhttplocal= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
     } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttplocal= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttplocal=false;
      }
     }
        if (!xmlhttplocal && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
         try {
          var xmlhttplocal = new XMLHttpRequest();
         } catch (e) {
          var xmlhttplocal=false;
          alert('couldn\'t create xmlhttp object');
         }
        }
        return(xmlhttplocal);
    }

    function sndReq(vote,id_num,ip_num,units) {
        var theUL = document.getElementById('unit_ul'+id_num); // the UL

        // switch UL with a loading div
        theUL.innerHTML = '<div class="loading"></div>';

        xmlhttp.open('get', 'rpc.php?j='+vote+'&q='+id_num+'&t='+ip_num+'&c='+units);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        xmlhttp.send(null); 
    }

    function handleResponse() {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200){

            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var update = new Array();

            if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
                update = response.split('|');
                changeText(update[0], update[1]);
            }
            }
        }
    }

    function changeText( div2show, text ) {
        // Detect Browser
        var IE = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
        var DOM = 0; 
        if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >=5) {DOM=1};

        // Grab the content from the requested "div" and show it in the "container"
        if (DOM) {
            var viewer = document.getElementById(div2show);
            viewer.innerHTML = text;
        }  else if(IE) {
            document.all[div2show].innerHTML = text;
        }
    }

    /* =============================================================== */
    var ratingAction = {
            'a.rater' : function(element){
                element.onclick = function(){

                var parameterString = this.href.replace(/.*\?(.*)/, "$1"); // onclick="sndReq('j=1&q=2&t=127.0.0.1&c=5');
                var parameterTokens = parameterString.split("&"); // onclick="sndReq('j=1,q=2,t=127.0.0.1,c=5');
                var parameterList = new Array();

                for (j = 0; j < parameterTokens.length; j++) {
                    var parameterName = parameterTokens[j].replace(/(.*)=.*/, "$1"); // j
                    var parameterValue = parameterTokens[j].replace(/.*=(.*)/, "$1"); // 1
                    parameterList[parameterName] = parameterValue;
                }
                var theratingID = parameterList['q'];
                var theVote = parameterList['j'];
                var theuserIP = parameterList['t'];
                var theunits = parameterList['c'];

                //for testing   alert('sndReq('+theVote+','+theratingID+','+theuserIP+','+theunits+')'); return false;
                sndReq(theVote,theratingID,theuserIP,theunits); return false;       
                }
            }

        };
    Behaviour.register(ratingAction);
```

**2.behavior.js**

```
    var Behaviour = {
    list : new Array,

    register : function(sheet){
        Behaviour.list.push(sheet);
    },

    start : function(){
        Behaviour.addLoadEvent(function(){
            Behaviour.apply();
        });
    },

    apply : function(){
        for (h=0;sheet=Behaviour.list[h];h++){
            for (selector in sheet){
                list = document.getElementsBySelector(selector);

                if (!list){
                    continue;
                }

                for (i=0;element=list[i];i++){
                    sheet[selector](element);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    addLoadEvent : function(func){
        var oldonload = window.onload;

        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                oldonload();
                func();
            }
        }
    }
}

Behaviour.start();


function getAllChildren(e) {
  // Returns all children of element. Workaround required for IE5/Windows. Ugh.
  return e.all ? e.all : e.getElementsByTagName('*');
}

document.getElementsBySelector = function(selector) {
  // Attempt to fail gracefully in lesser browsers
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) {
    return new Array();
  }
  // Split selector in to tokens
  var tokens = selector.split(' ');
  var currentContext = new Array(document);
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    token = tokens[i].replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');;
    if (token.indexOf('#') > -1) {
      // Token is an ID selector
      var bits = token.split('#');
      var tagName = bits[0];
      var id = bits[1];
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      if (tagName && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != tagName) {
        // tag with that ID not found, return false
        return new Array();
      }
      // Set currentContext to contain just this element
      currentContext = new Array(element);
      continue; // Skip to next token
    }
    if (token.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      // Token contains a class selector
      var bits = token.split('.');
      var tagName = bits[0];
      var className = bits[1];
      if (!tagName) {
        tagName = '*';
      }
      // Get elements matching tag, filter them for class selector
      var found = new Array;
      var foundCount = 0;
      for (var h = 0; h < currentContext.length; h++) {
        var elements;
        if (tagName == '*') {
            elements = getAllChildren(currentContext[h]);
        } else {
            elements = currentContext[h].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
          found[foundCount++] = elements[j];
        }
      }
      currentContext = new Array;
      var currentContextIndex = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k < found.length; k++) {
        if (found[k].className && found[k].className.match(new RegExp('\\b'+className+'\\b'))) {
          currentContext[currentContextIndex++] = found[k];
        }
      }
      continue; // Skip to next token
    }
    // Code to deal with attribute selectors
    if (token.match(/^(\w*)\[(\w+)([=~\|\^\$\*]?)=?"?([^\]"]*)"?\]$/)) {
      var tagName = RegExp.$1;
      var attrName = RegExp.$2;
      var attrOperator = RegExp.$3;
      var attrValue = RegExp.$4;
      if (!tagName) {
        tagName = '*';
      }
      // Grab all of the tagName elements within current context
      var found = new Array;
      var foundCount = 0;
      for (var h = 0; h < currentContext.length; h++) {
        var elements;
        if (tagName == '*') {
            elements = getAllChildren(currentContext[h]);
        } else {
            elements = currentContext[h].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
          found[foundCount++] = elements[j];
        }
      }
      currentContext = new Array;
      var currentContextIndex = 0;
      var checkFunction; // This function will be used to filter the elements
      switch (attrOperator) {
        case '=': // Equality
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName) == attrValue); };
          break;
        case '~': // Match one of space seperated words 
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName).match(new RegExp('\\b'+attrValue+'\\b'))); };
          break;
        case '|': // Match start with value followed by optional hyphen
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName).match(new RegExp('^'+attrValue+'-?'))); };
          break;
        case '^': // Match starts with value
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName).indexOf(attrValue) == 0); };
          break;
        case '$': // Match ends with value - fails with "Warning" in Opera 7
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName).lastIndexOf(attrValue) == e.getAttribute(attrName).length - attrValue.length); };
          break;
        case '*': // Match ends with value
          checkFunction = function(e) { return (e.getAttribute(attrName).indexOf(attrValue) > -1); };
          break;
        default :
          // Just test for existence of attribute
          checkFunction = function(e) { return e.getAttribute(attrName); };
      }
      currentContext = new Array;
      var currentContextIndex = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k < found.length; k++) {
        if (checkFunction(found[k])) {
          currentContext[currentContextIndex++] = found[k];
        }
      }
      // alert('Attribute Selector: '+tagName+' '+attrName+' '+attrOperator+' '+attrValue);
      continue; // Skip to next token
    }

    if (!currentContext[0]){
        return;
    }

    // If we get here, token is JUST an element (not a class or ID selector)
    tagName = token;
    var found = new Array;
    var foundCount = 0;
    for (var h = 0; h < currentContext.length; h++) {
      var elements = currentContext[h].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
      for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        found[foundCount++] = elements[j];
      }
    }
    currentContext = found;
  }
  return currentContext;
}

/* That revolting regular expression explained 
/^(\w+)\[(\w+)([=~\|\^\$\*]?)=?"?([^\]"]*)"?\]$/
  \---/  \---/\-------------/    \-------/
    |      |         |               |
    |      |         |           The value
    |      |    ~,|,^,$,* or =
    |   Attribute 
   Tag
*/
```

Comment: What 'Ajax conflict error'? Presumably there is an error/response message that you're failing to tell us about.

Comment: Use powerful and modern libraries or frameworks.

Comment: @Max If only I could downvote a comment.. sorry but, it's not always you want to use a heavy library, and wouldn't you want to make your own? or how a library is constructed in the first place.

Comment: Ajax rating system is working without reloading but In my website it's reloaded when I trying to rate.

Comment: @user2797600 Add `event` to the `onclick` function: `element.onclick = function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }`. Currently the rating system seems to use an `<a>` tag for its rating system, so when you `click`, it'll send you to itself (the same page).